# Recommended solutions, libraries or frameworks to build a repeatable copy/mirror tool

Tags: scripting, software-rec

I'm looking to satisfy the following use cases

- Occasionally automatically copy all data from a removable storage to fixed folder (and in reverse)
- Occasionally automatically sync a folder with a removable storage
- Move a local folder contents to a network mounted location

I think the following requirements are the most problematic:

- Detection if a newtork folder is mounted
- Detection if removable storage is attached
- Triggering an event upon storage being attached

The use case is similar to backup suites, but the outlined requirements seem not to be covered by `Duplicati` and other solutions.

The transportation of files is relatively easy, as it could be done with `rsync`. Wrappers around `rsync` also seem to be lacking on the trigger part.

I'm slightly overwhelmed by the solution space, as it could be done by triggering backups from `udev rules` as wells as a `make` build system that exits if no source/destination is found, etc.

I have the impression that my use case is more general and there should be a tool or framework to handle this. Is there a more general way of handling this?

Comment: sounds like a systemd service unit file, with dependencies on network units, mount units, and a udev rule to react to hardware. Possible also a systemd timer unit that "occasionally" triggers (e.g. 15 minutes after idling plus some randomized time). All this is already implemented :)

Comment: You are looking for unison. https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you, I've overlooked (and avoided) that part. Would you suggest to have one service unit file to cover each synchronisation, or a _big_ service unit file that watches all cases?

Comment: @IporSircer Thank you, I've looked into it but it seems to be missing the "detect" aspect. Can you point me if I've overlooked something?

Comment: @hipsterdoofus I'd go with one service per "task". One task seems to be removable->fixed folder, one task folder -> removable, and one task seems to be -> network location.

Comment: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#mountpoints

Comment: @IporSircer unison is a great solution for *how* to copy, not for how to manage the dependencies and automation for *when* to copy, and that's what this question is about, mostly.